# JDI UI Test Automation Framework Simple Java example project - run test

Tags: jdiframework

I am download Simple Java example project
Run SimpleTest
I see error

> Error:(12, 17) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   method domain()
>   location: @interface
>   com.epam.jdi.uitests.web.selenium.elements.pageobjects.annotations.JSite
>
> Error:(12, 1) java: annotation
>   @com.epam.jdi.uitests.web.selenium.elements.pageobjects.annotations.JSite
>   is missing a default value for the element 'value'

I'm changing `@JSite(**domain** = "https://epam.github.io/JDI/") to @JSite(**value** = "https://epam.github.io/JDI/")`

In the end, I got an error

> "ERROR: Can't download latest driver for CHROME. Exception null"

I changed the value `driver=${driver}` to `driver=chrome` in file test.properties,
commented on the line chrome in pom.xml
I see the same mistake
I saw the answers on the query

> "ERROR: Can't download latest driver for CHROME. Exception null"

But I can not imagine where you can still specify the property of the path to the driver

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\chromedriver_win32_2.1"));
ChromeDriver d1 = new ChromeDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

In file **JDIExampleSite** changing @JSite(value = "https://epam.github.io/JDI") (Remove the last slash)

In file **HomePage** changing @JPage(url = "/index.html", title = "Index Page") (We add "L" to htm and we get html)

In file **test.properties** remove the comment "drivers.folder=C:\" (I have a root chrome driver, If you are different, specify your path)

I also removed the comment from "drivers.version=2.23" in file **test.properties** and changed "driver=chrome" here